# Remove non-numeric and non-characters symbols from String

Tags: java, regex, character

So I found many posts where  you can use `"[^0-9.]"` to remove non-numeric characters , and `"[^\\p{L}\\s]+"` to remove non- characters..

But how to combain these two. ?

If i try something like

```
replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\s]+" + "[^0-9.]"
```

it's not working..

Comment: Are you also trying to ignore whitespaces with `\\s`?

Comment: yes, I need to ignore spaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just combine the character classes into one:

```
s = s.replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\s0-9.]+", "");
```

When you add the strings, the resulting regex pattern looks like `[^\\p{L}\\s]+[^0-9.]` that matches non-character and non-whitespace letters (1 or more occurrences) and 1 non-digit, non-period character.

In your case, you want to match a character (or 1 or more characters) that is not a digit, letter, whitespace, or period. Thus, the two negated character classes should just be merged into 1, not just concatenated.

If you also plan to exclude an underscore, you may try a shorter version:

```
s = s.replaceAll("[^\\w\\s.]+", "");
```

as `\w` matches `[\\p{L}0-9_]`.

Comment: yes Sir.. thats vey correct, and thanks for explaining.
Also, is there a way, to exclude some characters if needed ?

Lets say, I need not to  replace    `-`  (dash)  symbol ?

Comment: Add a hyphen to the end of the character class (`[^\\p{L}\\s0-9.-]+`).

Comment: You are trully the winner  !  Thanks alot.

 Last question would be, if you know any tutorials where I could learn more about this stuf.. I would be very glad..

Thanks again, works like a charm. !

Comment: Right now, let me recommend regexone.com for exercises and regular-expressions.info for reference. There are more helpful links, but I do have them at hand.

Comment: Just in case you work with Unicode strings, use `(?U)` modifier: `s = s.replaceAll("(?U)[^\\w\\s.]+", "");`